# Is Chen Stormstout considered a member of the Horde?

Tags: warcraft

In "WarCraft III: Reign of Chaos", we witnessed the formation of the modern Horde by Thrall and his allies. Cairne Bloodhoof and Vol'jin are both considered founding members and were also the racial leaders for their respective peoples. Also present, though, was the wandering Pandaren brewmaster Chen Stormstout. Chen was instrumental in their journeys across Kalimdor, but AFAIK he's not considered part of the Horde. Now that the Pandarens have joined both the Alliance and Horde, I would think he would have a place of honor in the Horde.

**Is Chen Stormstout considered a founding member of the Horde?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Chen was present during the events leading to the modern Horde's founding, he never swore any allegiance. The graphic novel [Bloodsworn](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Bloodsworn)  revealed that a member of any race wishing to join the Horde must swear an oath. Chen has never been depicted as declaring any allegiance to Horde or Alliance, but the Huojin Pandaren did by allying themselves and flying the Horde's colors.

Chen is best described as an independent, neutral character ala Taran Zhu, with the [Mists of Pandaria](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvYXoyxLv64) trailer summing up his stance quite perfectly.

Comment: During WoW's "Battlefield: Barrens" event, Chen says: "Years ago, I helped put the Horde together on these very sands. My... how times have changed", so while he does not consider himself a member of The Horde, he possibly considers himself a founder, and at the very least he knows he lent a hand in The Horde's creation.

Comment: I never realized that was supposed to be Chen in the MoP trailer - I always thought it was just a random Pandaren monk used to represent the new class for the expansion.